# Updating kali over https

Tags: kali-linux, repository, https

I'm using my college's wifi to update my Kali system but it's unable to fetch any data for some reason. I'm sure that the firewall doesn't block Kali.org because I tried opening it in my web browser and it opened successfully. My best guess is that the firewall blocks heavy packages based on the HTTP header's `content length` field but I'm not sure of it as I'm not even able to download small packages.

I want to try updating my system and download packages over HTTPS so I could be sure that this is( or isn't) the problem but I couldn't find a repository for it. The [official repository](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) is

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

which is HTTP. Do you know of any HTTPS repo?

PS: Could there be any other problem? Proxy is out of the question as we do not use proxies on our wireless network at all.

**EDIT**: Here's an example. But when I shifted to my mobile Internet, the same package installed without any error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
[sudo] password for papagolf: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aptitude-common aptitude-doc-en libclass-accessor-perl libcwidget3v5
  libio-string-perl libparse-debianchangelog-perl
Suggested packages:
  apt-xapian-index libcwidget-dev libxml-simple-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptitude aptitude-common aptitude-doc-en libclass-accessor-perl
  libcwidget3v5 libio-string-perl libparse-debianchangelog-perl
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,677 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 aptitude-common all 0.7.5-3
  Connection failed
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libcwidget3v5 amd64 0.5.17-4+b1
  Connection failed
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 aptitude amd64 0.7.5-3
  Connection failed
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 aptitude-doc-en all 0.7.5-3
  Connection failed
Err:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libclass-accessor-perl all 0.34-1
  Connection failed
Err:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libio-string-perl all 1.08-3
  Connection failed
Err:7 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libparse-debianchangelog-perl all 1.2.0-10
  Could not connect to http.kali.org:80 (192.99.200.113), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude-common_0.7.5-3_all.deb  Connection failed
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/c/cwidget/libcwidget3v5_0.5.17-4+b1_amd64.deb  Connection failed
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude_0.7.5-3_amd64.deb  Connection failed
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude-doc-en_0.7.5-3_all.deb  Connection failed
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/libc/libclass-accessor-perl/libclass-accessor-perl_0.34-1_all.deb  Connection failed
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/libi/libio-string-perl/libio-string-perl_1.08-3_all.deb  Connection failed
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/libp/libparse-debianchangelog-perl/libparse-debianchangelog-perl_1.2.0-10_all.deb  Could not connect to http.kali.org:80 (192.99.200.113), connection timed out
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Can you see the repository (http://http.kali.org/kali) in a browser?

Comment: I visited http://http.kali.org/kali/ using a browser and yes it loaded successfully.

Comment: That suggests that it's not a firewall issue, and you don't need to use HTTPS.  When you say "unable to fetch any data", what error do you actually see?  Please [edit the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/298815/edit) to include the exact message.

Comment: @JigglyNaga : I edited the question as you asked.

Comment: How about if you try retrieving one of the packages directly, eg. `wget http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude-common_0.7.5-3_all.deb` ?  Also try fetching it with the browser.

Comment: @JigglyNaga It worked. I can download it using both, browser and wget. But that won't solve the dependencies issue. Right?

Comment: Well, you *could* download all the packages manually and put them where `apt` needs them, but that would be messy.  Without knowing what exact restriction your internet provider has applied, nobody can reproduce the issue in order to suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an HTTPS repository for kali (April/2017); Please see https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-repository-https-support/

```
# apt install apt-transport-https # yeah, I didn't miss the irony of this
# # please save a copy of your sources.list file before overwriting
# echo "deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```